# Attach Visual Studio 2012 to a Unity game running in Android mobile, for Debugging

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a possibility to attach Visual Studio 2012 to a Unity game running on my Android device, so that I can debug the application.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/AttachingMonoDevelopDebuggerToAnAndroidDevice.html)? This is unity 5.6 docs but I think it should still work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try what SwiftingDuster has suggested.

Additionally , you need to connect your Android Device and keep Unity closed, MonoDevelop Running. So that when you click on Attach to Process (in Mono Develop) it should prompt with connected Android Device only.

Make

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012. I tried similar options in Visual studio 2012 and in Visual studio code, didn't work.

Comment: May be you should update Unity to latest 2018 version and also the Visual studio. This link might help - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/unity-tools/